# Print lots of info on a single line

Tags: python

I have this python code, which logs onto a bunch of juniper switches and grabs their serial numbers from the different cards installed into them.

Right now it prints out the information on different lines, but I'd like it all to be on a single line, so I can import it into a csv file a little easier.

This is the code:

```
from jnpr.junos import Device
import getpass

#Grab credentials
username = raw_input("Enter your username:")
password = getpass.getpass("Enter your password:")

with open('switchlist') as infile:
for host in infile:
    try:
        #Connect to devices in switchlsit file using username and password provided above
        dev = Device(host=host.strip(),  user=username, password=password)
        dev.open()
        # XML RPC Command for "show chassis"
        chassisInfo = dev.rpc.get_chassis_inventory()
        print "Switch: ", dev.facts['hostname']
        for chassis in chassisInfo.iter('chassis-module'):
            if "FPC" in chassis.find('name').text:
                print "Serial: ", chassis.find('name').text,chassis.find('serial-number').text

        for chassisPIC in chassisInfo.iter('chassis-sub-module'):
            if "PIC 0" in chassisPIC.find('name').text:
                continue
            if "PIC" in chassisPIC.find('name').text:
                print "Serial: ", chassisPIC.find('name').text,chassisPIC.find('serial-number').text
    except:
        print "error"
```

Any thoughts here?  I'm not really sure how I could do that.  Was thinking of somehow storing the info into variable, then printing them out, but I'm not sure how to do that.

When the script runs it currently looks like this:

```
Switch:  switch1
Serial:  FPC 0 TB3712345467
Serial:  PIC 1 RR3712345467
Serial:  PIC 2 RR3712345467
Switch:  switch2
Serial:  FPC 0 TB3712345467
Serial:  PIC 1 RR3712345467
Serial:  PIC 2 RR312345467
```

I'd like it to be something like

```
 switch switch1, fpc0 TB3712345467, pic1 TB3712345467, pic2 TB3712345467
```

Comment: If your end goal is to deal with csv you probably want to have a look at this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw all the data into a list and use `', '.join`.

```
for host in infile:
    data = []
    try:
        # Connect to devices in switchlsit file using username and password provided above
        dev = Device(host=host.strip(),  user=username, password=password)
        dev.open()
        # XML RPC Command for "show chassis"
        chassisInfo = dev.rpc.get_chassis_inventory()
        data.append("Switch: {}".format(dev.facts['hostname']))
        for chassis in chassisInfo.iter('chassis-module'):
            if "FPC" in chassis.find('name').text:
                data.append("Serial: {} {}".format(
                    chassis.find('name').text, 
                    chassis.find('serial-number').text)

        for chassisPIC in chassisInfo.iter('chassis-sub-module'):
            if "PIC 0" in chassisPIC.find('name').text:
                continue
            if "PIC" in chassisPIC.find('name').text:
                data.append("Serial: {} {}".format(
                    chassisPIC.find('name').text, 
                    chassisPIC.find('serial-number').text)
    except:
        print "error"
    finally:
        print(", ".join(data))
```

Although if your ultimate goal is to get this as a CSV, I'm unclear why you're printing it to screen. Maybe just:

```
all_data = []
# all the code written above, with the finally block changed to:
finally:
    print(", ".join(data))
    all_data.append(data)
```

Then once you've left your `for` loop, `all_data` is a list of lists of fields for each host. This is useful since you can then do:

```
import csv

headers = ['some', 'column', 'headers', 'go', 'here']
with open('path/to/outfile.csv', 'w') as outf:
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    writer.writerows(headers + all_data)
```

Comment: thanks, this works pretty well.  I was printing to the screen to just confirm the output.  I can send it all to a text file pretty easily now.

Answer (score 0):

**Fast, ugly answer:**

Replace calls to print by `sys.stdout.write`.

**Long answer:**

Ideally you would split your function into two functions:

- one that does the scanning. Compiles relevant data into a list.
- one that does the formatting. Spits out data from the list in the proper format.

Those are two different tasks, so they each should have their own function. Actually, if it was already split, you would'nt have had to ask.

For dealing with CSV, as someone pointed out, your formatting function can leverage python's [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).